# Calling javascript within Chrome from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, mshtml

We have a .NET Windows desktop application (C#) that launches an accompanying web page in an external browser window, and then needs to communicate with that page via javascript.

We have successfully done this with Internet Explorer, using mshtml.HTMLDocument. We iterate over the ShellWindows to find the open Internet Explorer window, and then can do something like the following:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = iExplorer.Document;
mshtml.IHTMLWindow2 win = doc.parentWindow as mshtml.IHTMLWindow2;
win.execScript("myJavaScriptFunction('arg1','arg2')", "javascript");
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this with Chrome? We can find the Chrome window, but is there an equivalent API we can call into to execute javascript on the desired page?

Comment: Have you looked at signalr?  Http://github.com/signalr  That's assuming it's an ASP.NET app... what type of C# app is it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's a C# windows desktop application.

Comment: Do you own and maintain the website code?  If so, what's it written in?

Comment: There is a way to do this in limited circumstances. If you launch Chrome in debug mode, then use the JSON/WebSocket4Net you can communicate with chrome and give it javascript commands.

Comment: This is all enterprise software - big and complex, much of it generated by JSPs as well as proprietary code generation. And thanks for your response John. It sounds like this is not very do-able in a "normal" environment, not in debug mode (or test automation mode, as I've seen elsewhere while researching this...)

Comment: I've never done this, but apparently it should be possible as there are UI QA automation tools like Ranorex or Selenium doing this. I'd would start looking at [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) for Selenium. Please share your research results.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, and apologies to those interested in how this resolved. It's been decided that we require IE be used for the parts of our application suite that communicate between .NET and the browser. Sorry to abandon the effort here, but thanks, folks.